# Is there any way to get only json data if I use getText() method

Tags: java, json, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

In one of the scenario I have to validate the json content, but when I am using getText() method to retrieve the content, it's giving me all element. I need to get only json content so that I can validate.
I want only json object should fetch and same I can save in json file for further validation.

e.g. This is how div looks:

```
   <div id="postMessageDiv">
        <div class="msg">
            <span class="MethodNameMsg">Post Message Function/ Method Name:</span>
            <span class="MethodName">loadModule</span>
        </div>
        <br>Data: 
        <br>
        {
      "fnToCall": "loadModule",
      "finappId": "10003592",
      "containerFinapp": true
    }
    <br>
    Page Height Sent By Framework:::: 656
    <br>
    Page Height Sent By Framework:::: 815
    <br>
    Page Height Sent By Framework:::: 996
    <div class="msg">
                                <span class="MethodNameMsg">Post Message Function/ Method Name:</span>
                                <span class="MethodName">loadModule</span>
                            </div>
                            <br>Data: 
                            <br>
                            {
      "fnToCall": "loadModule",
      "finappId": "10003593",
      "containerFinapp": true
    }
    <br>Page Height Sent By Framework:::: 684
    <br>Page Height Sent By Framework:::: 656
    <div class="msg">
    <span class="MethodNameMsg">Post Message Function/ Method Name:</span>
    <span class="MethodName">accountStatus</span>
                                            </div>
                                            <br>Data: 
                                            <br>
                                            {
      "fnToCall": "accountStatus",
      "action": "exit",
      "sites": [
        {
          "providerAccountId": 10102587,
          "bankName": "Dag Site (United States)",
          "status": "IN_PROGRESS",
          "providerId": 16441,
          "requestId": "NGj/NgqlHsZ6W2k8NcWSJY3MSkY=",
          "statusCode": "ACCT_SUMMARY_RECEIVED"
        }
      ]
    }</div>
```

Output response: If I am using getText(), I am getting below as my response:

```
 Post Message Function/ Method Name: loadModule
        
        Data: 
        {
          "fnToCall": "loadModule",
          "finappId": "10003592",
          "containerFinapp": true
        }
        Page Height Sent By Framework:::: 656
        Page Height Sent By Framework:::: 830
        Page Height Sent By Framework:::: 849
        Page Height Sent By Framework:::: 831
        Post Message Function/ Method Name: loadModule
        
        Data: 
        {
          "fnToCall": "loadModule",
          "finappId": "10003593",
          "containerFinapp": true
        }
        Page Height Sent By Framework:::: 684
        Post Message Function/ Method Name: accountStatus
        
        Data: 
        {
          "fnToCall": "accountStatus",
          "action": "exit",
          "sites": [
            {
              "providerAccountId": 10102575,
              "bankName": "Dag Site",
              "status": "IN_PROGRESS",
              "providerId": 16441,
              "requestId": "P7b1oRBi4geKPVhmS7cPRnqcVPU=",
              "statusCode": "ACCT_SUMMARY_RECEIVED"
            }
          ]
        }
```

For getText only main div will work and I need only json object for validation. If I can get json object I can easily validate the content using json libraries

Answer (score 0):

getText() returns the innertext between the nodes, there is no option to fetch json only. So you will have to parse the returned data in the programming language you used.

Comment: I don't want to save the value in file and than validate. Can we use br tag to fetch data and than apply assertion?

Comment: there is no option in Selenium to look for specific tags within the inner text. you will have to fetch the entire text.